# DNS changes after migration - how to handle it?

Tags: php, wordpress

never touched WordPress before but been tasked to migrate a site from a hosted solution into AWS. Migration has been completed but now I am wondering when/if I should change the site URL in the wp-config.php.

The following two lines are in the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
```

My question is, if I change the DNS address to point to the new address in AWS - will the site URL and home URL in WordPress change dynamically? or do I have to manually input the URL in the wp-config file?

Thanks

Comment: No, it is not changed automatically. You need to change URL t in wp-config file other wise replace old URL to new URL on database side

Comment: Ideally, you should not require to change anything. When to update the DNS to point your domain name to the new AWS instance, request for the site should be catered without any change.